# jQuery Autocomplete control in DataTables input field

Tags: datatables, jquery-autocomplete

I have an inline [Editable](http://goo.gl/71r6vk) row.

On double clicking a DataTables row, the row is changed to editable. On hitting enter the edited row is saved and is restored as a table row. Now I need to change an editable input filed as Autocomplete Using a jQuery plugin. [This is my fiddle.](http://goo.gl/71r6vk)

Comment: not sure that this is it https://caffeinatedcoding.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/roll-your-own-autocomplete-table-with-jquery-and-datatables/ but it might give you some idea...

Answer (score 1):

#### CAUSE

You have forgot to include jQuery UI CSS and JS files.

#### SOLUTION

Corrected code for invoking Autocomplete widget is shown below.

```
$("#typ")
   .focus()
   .autocomplete({
      source: type1
   });
```

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KVSDs/14/) for code and demonstration.